# Is it possible to remove schema in dconf database?

Tags: command-line, dconf

I have executed below specify code:

```
dconf load / << EOF 
[org/compiz/profiles/unity-lowgfx/plugins/core12]
toggle-maximized=['disabled']
EOF
```

The above specified schema was **not valid**, but schema was store permanently in my **dconf database**. Is it possible to permanently remove above schema and key, values pair in my dconf database?

Comment: Instead of  "core" I  have accidentally typed "core12" and executed. so it's not an valid schema @jacob